# Ajax call to Asp.net Web Method using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am using a jquery method, to send information (namely only member identification #) from client side to the server side.

The server side has the traditional Web Method implemented so as to capture data sent and execute SQL queries based on it.

[Web-service-method-using-jQuery](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx)

However until now I have been returning a single string from the server side back to the client side after the SQL query.

Wondering what would be the best way to return a complicated series of strings... member Identification number, start date, end date, type of member... depending on the type of the member, there can be multiple start dates and end dates.

Should I be looking into XML ?

Comment: you should return a json object to the client

Comment: with a Json object will i have issues, if there are multiple values for start date and end date under the same member ID ?

also would I use eval() in javascript to parse thru my object?

Comment: In addition, I want to pass the complicated set of values from server to client side...only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about returning even a datatable

```
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "YourPage.aspx/doSomething",
data: "{'id':'1'}",
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) {
    var returnedstring = data.d;
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);//if you want your data in json
  }
});
```

aspx:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(int id)
{
   ....
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = anothermethodReturningdt(id)

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}
```

You can use [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for serializing .Net objects

**Edit**

you can also do this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(int id)
{
   Product product = new Product();
   product.Name = "Apple";
   product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
   product.Price = 3.99M;
   product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
}
```

The point is you can serialize any type of object, arrays, collections etc and then pass it back to the calling script.

Comment: can you elaborate on anothermethodReturningdt(id) ? and what also what does it mean to return a database? This is a stateless application, what kind of effect will returning an entire database have ?

Comment: I am not talking about the whole database. You can return any kind of object or collection of data including [Datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

Comment: When implementing WebMethods, you should avoid manually serializing objects. http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/