# how to save data in database using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to jquery. I often do my coding in c# and Now i have to work with jquery. I Know basic of jquery. Just few functions of jquery. But now I want to do some advance thing . I want to save update delete the data in sql server from my asp.net page using jquery. I tried a jquery code for this but it is not working. I am not able to get what is the error and where i am going wrong. Here is my code of jquery which i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Default2.aspx/InsertMethod',
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtusername').value + "','password':'" + document.getElementById("txtpassword").value + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#txtusername').val('');
                        $('#txtpassword').val('');
                        alert("record has been saved in database");

                    },
                    error: function () {
                    console.log('there is some error');
                    }

                });

            });

        });
```

I create a web method in c# code where i write the code for save data in sql server and calling that web method in jquery. But this code is not working 
Here is my C# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string InsertMethod(string username, string password)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert jquerydata values('" + username + "','" + password + "'", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        return "true";

    }
```

Please tell me how can I do it.

Comment: i guess your code is quiet ok .. are you getting any error in javascript console ??

Comment: jQuery is client-side, ```$.ajax()``` is just passing values to a page, it don't make difference which language is getting these values. Your error probably is server-side.

Comment: When you execute that code, what happens?  Can you post the error you are getting from your javascript console?  

Also, jQuery and ASP.NET are different technologies.  ASP.NET is a server side framework for handling HTTP, rendering webpages etc.  jQuery is a client side (browser) scripting library.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Nothing happens? Do you have any errors in console? Try to put a breakpoint in your method to see if it is being called.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code for the Default2.aspx/InsertMethod URL that you're calling.

Comment: @Polaris878 see i am totaly new in jqeury i dnt know anything about it please tell me how to see the error and and what i have to

Comment: @Liam then please tell me what is the right way to do so i am new to jquery

Comment: @TimS check it now please

Comment: You are missing `)` in your `SQL` command as I can see.

Comment: Turns out you can do that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14819607/542251) inlcudes an article and some examples.

Comment: BTW, concatenating SQL like that is a SQL Injection Attack risk. Use a Stored Procedure, or at the very least a parameterized query. Also, @Liam's comment should be your answer.

Comment: @ChruS no there check code there is sqlcommand

Comment: @TimS i know it but it is just for practice not for live project i will do it by procedures on live project

Comment: No, @ChruS is right. You are missing a `)` in your SQL. Should be: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert jquerydata values('" + username + "','" + password + "')", con);`

Comment: @TimS check line number 7 there is sqlcommand in c# code

Comment: @manirajput Sure, if you are using Chrome (probably the easiest one to start with) open your page and then hit `CTRL + SHIFT + I`.  This will open the Chrome dev tools aka the JavaScript console.  Then, click on your button which performs your jQuery code.  In the "Console" tab in the dev tools, you should see an error (if there is one).  You can then click on the error and it will show you where the error is in your code.

Comment: I did check line number 7. And I told you there is an error in that line and provided you with the fix. Time for you to check your own code now.

Comment: @Polaris878 okk i did it it show me message there is some error.. that message which i define in error function... what its meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery seems to be fine. 
Just make sure your method is invoked. You can add a break point and debug your c# method.

In your c# code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert jquerydata values('" + username + "','" + password + "'", con);
```

I guess you are missing 'into' keyword.

You can also debug your jquery using the 'debugger' keyword and make sure you uncheck disable script debugging option in the IE-->Internet Options-->Advance-->under Browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it works:

**Default2.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO19542105.Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SO19542105: how to save data in database using jquery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default2.aspx/InsertMethod",
                    data: "{'username':'" + $("#txtusername").val() + "', 'password':'" + $("#txtpassword").val() + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#txtusername").val("");
                        $("#txtpassword").val("");
                        alert("record has been saved in database");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("there is some error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtusername" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" id="txtpassword" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="button" id="Button1" value="OK" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Default2.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SO19542105
{
    public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string InsertMethod(string username, string password)
        {
            using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO jquerydata(username, password) VALUES(@username, @password)";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this but its give me this error in console

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Did you debug through the code at all to see what exact error you're getting? Could be as simple as a bad connection string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write Static method in C# i.e. in aspx.cs page to insert data

[WebMethod]
    public static void AddRecord(string username, string password)
    {
        //SIMPLE SQL QUERY INSERT INTO
        {
            using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO jquerydata(username, password) VALUES(@username, @password)";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            return "true";
        }
        }
    }



create a html to accept two fields and insert data on click of button

<script src="3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Button1").on('click', function (e) {


            var userDetails = {
            username:$('#txtusername').val(),
            password: $('#txtpassword').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "pagename.aspx/AddRecord",
                data: JSON.stringify(userDetails),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                var result = response.d;
                if (result == "success") {
                    $("#msg").html("New record addded successfully  :)").css("color", "green");
                }

            }

            function OnErrorCall(response) {
                $("#msg").html("Error occurs  :(").css("color", "red");
            }

        });

    });

</script>



<form id="form1">
    <div id="Tree">
       <input type="text" id="txtusername" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" id="txtpassword" placeholder="password" />
    <input type="button" id="Button1" value="OK" />
    </div>
</form>
```